# Axon distributed query bus?

Tags: axon

In AxonFramework, it is possible to distribute events and commands using message brokers, like RabbitMQ for instance.

I wonder it is possible to do the same with queries, I can't find anything on docs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's completely correct that you can't find it in the docs, because it isn't build yet. At least, not as open source software yet.

You've currently only got the option to use the `SimpleQueryBus` implementation. So no corresponding `DistributedQueryBus` (e.g. like the `DistributedCommandBus`).
For maintenance I just created an [issue](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/613) for it on GitHub. That way you can track it's progress.

Another option would be to use [AxonHub](https://axoniq.io/product-overview/axonhub). AxonHub will allow you to distributed all message forms within a (non-)Axon application, like commands, events and queries a like.